# Workflow using virtualenv and pip

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have python2.6 and django1.2.3 already installed on my system (Ubuntu 10.x).
This is the setup i use for most of my projects. But for some projects I need sandboxed environments, different django version, some extra python modules and sometimes even different python version.

So, I am trying to use pip and virtualenv now,but I am unable to change python and django version. Will I have to remove default setup and move all existing projects into 1 virtualenv. Can I avoid this? Even if I do that, how can I specify a different version of python?

If I have to remove the old settings. How do i do that? I have currently most of the things installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/` but I am not sure if there is anything installed anywhere else also.

If I have a completely blank setup with just Ubuntu, what is the ideal workflow? Is it this one?

```
Install python
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools 
$ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv 
$ sudo easy_install pip
$ sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
```

Comment: virtualenv will save your life - good call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to do:

```
virtualenv --python=/path/to/python/version --no-site-packages ENV_NAME
```

For example:

```
virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.6 --no-site-packages my_project_env
```

If you follow this for your projects you should be able to have a separate configuration for each one.

Comment: `--no-site-packages` is deprecated now; this is the default behaviour now. if you want to enable access to site packages, you have to pass `--system-site-packages` explicit during the call to `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 5):

I have installed every Python verison I need (which is 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.1 and also 3.2) from source. That's always the best thing to do, so you don't mess up the system Python.

I installed them in /opt. Like so (you need a bunch of Ubuntu packages too, first):

```
./configure --prefix /opt/pythonxx
make -j2; make install # j2 is a nice trick there for dualcores not everyone knows.
```

Then I for each version install the things I need. I start with installing Distribute:

```
wget http://nightly.ziade.org/distribute_setup.py
/opt/pythonxx/bin/python distribute_setup.py
```

(Except for Python 3, who needs distribute_setup3.py)
Then I can install pip

```
/opt/pythonxx/bin/easy_install pip
```

And virtualenv:

```
/opt/pythonxx/bin/pip install virtualenv
```

(Virtualenv3 or virtualenv5 for Python 3)

And that's it! If I want to make a virtualenv using Python 2.4, I do:

```
/opt/python24/bin/virtualenv foobar
```

And Python 2.7:

```
/opt/python27/bin/virtualenv foobar
```

Running python is just

```
/opt/python24/bin/python
```

Etc. I *never* install anything in the above Pythons except these modules, and PIL (because PIL is a pain, but now there is Pillow, so you don't have to do that either). I use zc.buildout and virtualenv to keep the pythons clean.

Comment: I made a question to make a list of all needed packages, because I always spend half an hour on that each time I install a new Ubuntu. :) http://askubuntu.com/questions/21547/what-are-the-packages-libraries-i-should-install-before-compiling-python-from-sou

Answer (score 1):

You can use `virtualenv --no-site-packages ENVNAME` and that will make sure the default Django in your system Python won't be included in your new environment.

For different versions of Python, you can [follow these instructions from a superuser.com post](https://superuser.com/questions/28822/preferred-way-to-install-multiple-python-versions-on-ubuntu-jaunty).